# Microdata Extraction with MicrodataExtractor of Any23

Tags: java, rdf, extract, microdata, any23

I am trying to understand microdata extraction with Any23, but can't find much of useful documentation.

Can anybody give me a simple example of how to use MicrodataExtractor to extract microdata from HTML pages into RDF document in java?

Comment: Hi, Sherzad, and welcome to SO. Please read  careful “[How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: This may help you [Microdata extraction from HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034610/microdata-extraction-from-html-in-java)