# Extract JSON-LD from HTML using Apache Any23

Tags: java, extract, json-ld, any23

My aim is to extract structured data from webpages. I'm using the code mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27034610/5676586). I'm using [Apache Any23 CLI](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.any23/apache-any23-cli/2.0) library dependency in my Spring project.

By using this, I'm able to extract the HTML5 Microdata (Schema.org) from webpages. But, I can't extract the JSON-LD format present in the webpages. When I checked [Apache Any23](https://any23.apache.org/)'s documentation, JSON-LD format is supported in it. Didn't find any further documentations on it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you create a new Any23 extractor with `new Any23()` it should work out of the box. If you use another constructor like `Any23(String... extractorNames)` you have to make make sure that the correct one is added for embedded JSON LD, which is `"html-embedded-jsonld"`.

Now if there are any errors in the extraction process, Any23 drops them silently. (It's great, I know!)

I found it is possible to set a breakpoint in the `org.apache.any23.extractorExtractionResultImpl` method `notifyIssue`. With this you may be able to find a more detailed reason for your problems.